# How do I remove all attributes from one XML element?

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace, xml-parsing

I have the following string containing XML:

```
var mystring = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?adf version="1.0"?>
<adf>
<example url="https://someurl.com/?id=123&amp;hash=6WHnYZwE" 
anotherurl="https://someurl.com/status?id=123;hash=6WHnYZwE" something="Hi">
    <status>new</status>
    <requestdate>2017-11-15T19:45:23-05:00</requestdate>
    <Apples>
        <color>red</color>
        <origin>Washington</make>
    </Apples>
</example>
</adf>";
```

I want to remove the attributes from the `<example>` element so that this

```
<example url="https://someurl.com/?id=123&amp;hash=6WHnYZwE" anotherurl="https://someurl.com/status?id=123;hash=6WHnYZwE" something="Hi">
```

becomes this

```
<example>
```

I tried using `String.Replace` to replace the attributes with an empty string, but the attributes aren't always the same. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It's XML. Use an XML parser.

Comment: and if you're not allowed to use XML parser find the index of "<example", then first index of ">" afterwards. select the substring and replace that substring with "<example>"

Comment: Same as the 1rst comment! With the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx) in bonus

Comment: Thanks. Looking at this now...

Comment: I dont understand how to select the substring and replace that substring with "<example>".

Comment: I have the start and end index:             var startIndex = xmlString.IndexOf("<example");
            var endIndex = xmlString.IndexOf(">", 109);

Comment: To clarify what's being said about XML: Don't think of this as replacing a string. Think of it as finding an element called `example` in an XML document and deleting its `InnerText` - IOW deleting everything inside the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little bit rusty with my XML parsing so I'm sure this can be improved.

```
public void DeleteContentsOfExampleElement()
{
    var mystring = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?><?adf 
version=""1.0""?>  
<adf>  
<example url=""https://someurl.com/?id=123&amp;hash=6WHnYZwE"" 
anotherurl=""https://someurl.com/status?id=123;hash=6WHnYZwE"" 
something=""Hi"">
<status>new</status>  
<requestdate>2017-11-15T19:45:23-05:00</requestdate>
<Apples>
    <color>red</color>
    <origin>Washington</origin>
</Apples>
</example>
</adf>";
    var document = new XmlDocument();
    document.LoadXml(mystring);
    var exampleElements = document.GetElementsByTagName("example");
    foreach (XmlNode exampleElement in exampleElements)
    {
        exampleElement.Attributes?.RemoveAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: Edited - after looking more closely, you just want to remove the attributes, not clear the contents of the element.

Comment: This works beautifully! I also have it working using substring. Thanks!

Comment: var startIndex = xmlString.IndexOf("<example");
            var endIndex = xmlString.IndexOf("<", startIndex + 1);
            var substringExample = xmlString.Substring(startIndex, endIndex);
            xmlString = xmlString.Replace(substringExample, "<example>");